# Double for-loop filtering data frame with grepl

Tags: r, for-loop, filter, grepl

I have one question; I would like to filter each of the columns Pair_1 until Pair_4 in the data frame 'data01' on each of the character patterns listed in 'pexl07'.

Data frame data01 looks like this:

```
               Pair_1                     Pair_2                     Pair_3                   Pair_4
453  lupinespringcereal       grasscloverleyquinoa   springcerealspringcereal         camelinacamelina
1073 lupinespringcereal     grasscloverleycamelina   springcerealspringcereal             quinoaquinoa
1330 lupinespringcereal     grasscloverleycamelina         quinoaspringcereal             lupinequinoa
1373 lupinespringcereal     grasscloverleycamelina               quinoaquinoa       lupinespringcereal
1698     lupinecamelina grasscloverleyspringcereal               quinoaquinoa springcerealspringcereal
1910 lupinespringcereal       springcerealcamelina grasscloverleyspringcereal             lupinequinoa
1947 lupinespringcereal       springcerealcamelina       grasscloverleyquinoa       lupinespringcereal
1979 lupinespringcereal         springcerealquinoa grasscloverleyspringcereal           lupinecamelina
2141       lupinequinoa   springcerealspringcereal     grasscloverleycamelina       lupinespringcereal
2745     lupinecamelina   springcerealspringcereal       grasscloverleyquinoa springcerealspringcereal
```

Pexl07 looks like this(for the sake of example):

```
                       V1
1             quinoaquinoa
2 springcerealspringcereal
```

I have tried many different things, using for(), filter(), subset(), grepl.sub() and grepl() but I do not manage to make it work, probably because I don't understand the indexing with the loops. Options without loops are also welcome.

This piece works on a single column and a single pattern:

```
data02 <- filter(data01, !grepl(paste(pexl07[1 , 1]), paste(data01[ ,1 ]))
```

However how do I make it work automatically, for all the expressions under pexl07 and on all the columns of data01?

I tried some variations of this, but it doesn't return what i would like:

```
for (j in ncol(data01))  {
  for (i in 1:nrow(pexl07)) {
    data02 <- filter(data01,
                         !grepl(paste(pexl07[j, ]), paste(data01[ ,i]))) 
  } 
}
```

To be clear, I want it to end up like this:

```
                 Pair_1                 Pair_2                     Pair_3             Pair_4
1330 lupinespringcereal grasscloverleycamelina         quinoaspringcereal       lupinequinoa
1910 lupinespringcereal   springcerealcamelina grasscloverleyspringcereal       lupinequinoa
1947 lupinespringcereal   springcerealcamelina       grasscloverleyquinoa lupinespringcereal
1979 lupinespringcereal     springcerealquinoa grasscloverleyspringcereal     lupinecamelina
```

with dput:

```
structure(list(Pair_1 = structure(c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("grasscloverleycamelina", 
"grasscloverleyquinoa", "lupinecamelina", "lupinegrasscloverley", 
"lupinequinoa", "lupinespringcereal"), class = "factor"), Pair_2 = structure(c(3L, 
9L, 9L, 11L), .Label = c("camelinacamelina", "camelinagrasscloverley", 
"grasscloverleycamelina", "grasscloverleyquinoa", "grasscloverleyspringcereal", 
"quinoagrasscloverley", "quinoaquinoa", "quinoaspringcereal", 
"springcerealcamelina", "springcerealgrasscloverley", "springcerealquinoa", 
"springcerealspringcereal"), class = "factor"), Pair_3 = structure(c(11L, 
7L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("camelinacamelina", "camelinagrasscloverley", 
"camelinaquinoa", "camelinaspringcereal", "grasscloverleycamelina", 
"grasscloverleyquinoa", "grasscloverleyspringcereal", "quinoacamelina", 
"quinoagrasscloverley", "quinoaquinoa", "quinoaspringcereal", 
"springcerealcamelina", "springcerealquinoa", "springcerealspringcereal"
), class = "factor"), Pair_4 = structure(c(6L, 6L, 7L, 5L), .Label = c("camelinacamelina", 
"camelinagrasscloverley", "grasscloverleycamelina", "grasscloverleyspringcereal", 
"lupinecamelina", "lupinequinoa", "lupinespringcereal", "quinoagrasscloverley", 
"quinoaquinoa", "quinoaspringcereal", "springcerealcamelina", 
"springcerealquinoa", "springcerealspringcereal"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(1330L, 
1910L, 1947L, 1979L), class = "data.frame")
```

dput pexl07:

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("quinoaquinoa", 
"springcerealspringcereal"), class = "factor")), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

dput data01:

```
  structure(list(Pair_1 = structure(c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 6L), .Label = c("grasscloverleycamelina", 
    "grasscloverleyquinoa", "lupinecamelina", "lupinegrasscloverley", 
    "lupinequinoa", "lupinespringcereal"), class = "factor"), Pair_2 = structure(c(4L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 9L), .Label = c("camelinacamelina", "camelinagrasscloverley", 
    "grasscloverleycamelina", "grasscloverleyquinoa", "grasscloverleyspringcereal", 
    "quinoagrasscloverley", "quinoaquinoa", "quinoaspringcereal", 
    "springcerealcamelina", "springcerealgrasscloverley", "springcerealquinoa", 
    "springcerealspringcereal"), class = "factor"), Pair_3 = structure(c(14L, 
    14L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 7L), .Label = c("camelinacamelina", "camelinagrasscloverley", 
    "camelinaquinoa", "camelinaspringcereal", "grasscloverleycamelina", 
    "grasscloverleyquinoa", "grasscloverleyspringcereal", "quinoacamelina", 
    "quinoagrasscloverley", "quinoaquinoa", "quinoaspringcereal", 
    "springcerealcamelina", "springcerealquinoa", "springcerealspringcereal"
    ), class = "factor"), Pair_4 = structure(c(1L, 9L, 6L, 7L, 13L, 
    6L), .Label = c("camelinacamelina", "camelinagrasscloverley", 
    "grasscloverleycamelina", "grasscloverleyspringcereal", "lupinecamelina", 
    "lupinequinoa", "lupinespringcereal", "quinoagrasscloverley", 
    "quinoaquinoa", "quinoaspringcereal", "springcerealcamelina", 
    "springcerealquinoa", "springcerealspringcereal"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(453L, 
    1073L, 1330L, 1373L, 1698L, 1910L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated my answer 
If I understand you correctly now, you want to remove the observation.
In R, that's denoted by a missing value which is `NA`.
Instead of storing what you want to remove in a dataframe, store in a vector, easier to use in filter that way.

and if you want to remove the whole row, let me know , will have to think of a slightly diff solution

I am using tidyverse to achieve what you want.
code below

```
#convert pexl07 to a vector
pexl07 <-pexl07$V1
library(tidyr)
data01 %>%
gather(pair,cereal) %>%
group_by(pair) %>%
mutate(index = row_number()) %>%
mutate(cereal = ifelse(cereal %in% pexl07,NA,cereal)) %>%
spread(pair,cereal)
```

<del>You're not really filtering,but filtering out by replacing characters with blanks. 
So I am replacing the columns in your data frame with "" (blank) where it equals
the condition that one of the expressions in pexl07.
Using gsub to do this and regularexpressions (regex).
read up on `?gsub`.
I am using sapply, this will apply to each column</del>

<del>sapply(data01, function(col) 
    gsub("quinoaquinoa|springcerealspringcereal","",col))</del>

<del>and if you're using dplyr, the `.` indicates the column.
mutate_all will mutate all columns.</del>

<del>#dplyr version
    data01 %>%
    mutate_all(funs(gsub("quinoaquinoa|springcerealspringcereal","",.)))</del>

Comment: Thanks! I don't think i want to replace with blanks, I would like to the whole row/observation to be removed.
Also, the number of rows in pexl07 may however vary as well as the content, so I don't want to type it in everytime. How can i easily add all whatever is in pexl07 to the gsub function?

Comment: Yes I want to remove the whole row, not replace with NA. This is visible in my desired output above, in this case that would mean that 4 observations are left after filtering out all observations that contain these patterns.